# Storyboard doesn't recognise custom segue identifier

Tags: swift, storyboard, segue

The goal is to unwind from secondVC to firstVC. And I want to do it from the scene itself, but Xcode doesn't recognise this segue.

What I'm doing is:

1. Control-drag from the secondVC scene in the Document Outline to the secondVC's Exit
2. Choose my unwind segue, that I created on firstVC
3. Give newly created segue an identifier - "SaveData".
4. Trying to call that segue through "performSegue" function

   performSegue(withIdentifier: SaveData, sender: self)

But it shows a mistake, that identifier doesn't exist - "Cannot find 'SaveData' in scope"

Here is the screenshot

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Xcode 14.0.1

Comment: 3.  "saveData" and 4. "SaveData" one is capitalized the other not.... may this be the mismatch

Comment: @popeinvestor No, they both have name "SaveData". It's just I wrote it here uncapitalised. Corrected. Thank you for suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG, I forgot that identifier should be put in quotation marks.
Should be like this:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "SaveData", sender: self)
```